# a skunk that can't stink, but can blind you temporarily?

Tags: creature-design, fauna, zoology

I want put a skunk in my story that doesn't spray stinky toxic spray (mixture of sulfur-containing 
chemicals such as thiols ) but it can blind you temporarily and can also causes inflammation

what other kind of mixture of subtances can my skunk can have?

can my skunk can have Capsaicin (active component of chili peppers) and 1,4-benzoquinone (found in Bombardier beetles) in my mixture?

Comment: Cobra venom can blind, but that can be permanent. I wonder whether an animal that squirts a gummy liquid at your eyes might do the job.

Comment: You have asked about a sight incapacitating creature short time ago. If this is a really different question, please make the difference visible